# How to make jQuery .stop() work for toggling animations

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I just made a demo of my project. I strongly suggest that you check my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ealonwang/yxdqtm79/) and see what exactly happens.

I also put the code here.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="slideApp" ng-controller="slideCtrl">
    <input type="button" value="Slide Down" ng-click="toggleSlide()">
    <br>
    <div style="display:none" slide-toggle>
        <a class="slide hide-slide" href="#">Slide Up</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

AngularJs:

```
var app = angular.module("slideApp", []);

app.controller("slideCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.slide = false;
    $scope.toggleSlide = function() {
        $scope.slide = true;
    }
});

app.directive("slideToggle", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch("slide", function(newVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                    $(element).slideDown().delay(2000).slideUp();
                } 
                scope.slide = false;
            })

            $(element).find(".hide-slide").on("click", function() {
                $(element).stop(true, true).slideUp();
            })
        }
    }
})
```

My problem is:

When "Slide Down" is clicked, the panel will slide down and last for 2 seconds before it automatically slides up.

Now do this: 
1. repeatly click "Slide Down" to show the panel and then click "Slide Up" immediately to hide the panel; 
2. after doing above for several times, click "Slide Down" immediately (don't click "Slide Up" this time), you will see that the panel slides down and slides up really quickly, while the panel is supposed to slide up after 2 seconds delay.

I know why this does not work ([jQuery .Stop() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)).

> If more than one animation method is called on the same element, the
>   later animations are placed in the effects queue for the element.
>   These animations will not begin until the first one completes. When
>   .stop() is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately.

But does anyone have the solution that makes panel slide up after 2 seconds delay? I really appreciate it if you have a solution to make it work and update my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ealonwang/yxdqtm79/). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problems here. The first is that repeatedly clicking slideDown causes the queue to build up. The fix is easy, add .stop(true,true) to it. This will keep it open for longer if you repeatedly click slide down, and then close 2 seconds after the last time it is clicked. (@TedWhitehead showed this in his answer)

```
$(element).stop(true,true).slideDown().delay(2000).slideUp();
```

Next, when you click slideUp, you don't need to clear the queue since at the end of the queue you're going to slide it up anyway. Instead, just jump to the end of the current animation (which would be the delay,) and don't slide it back up.

```
$(element).stop(false,true);
```

It simply ends the delay and continues on with the next thing in the queue, the slideUp.
https://jsfiddle.net/yxdqtm79/42/

Comment: This is the answer! Thanks so much Kevin! You saved my day!

Comment: @Ealon One small criticism, It would have made your question simpler if you removed the angular component from the question. The whole problem could have been recreated with just jQuery which would have made your question simpler.

Comment: Yes, I will follow your criticism in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add another `stop()` on line 16:

```
$(element).stop(true, true).slideDown().delay(2000).slideUp();
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w2pj86ym/)

Comment: Thanks. But it does not work when I do "click slide down then click slide up immediately" several times.

Comment: I guess I don't exactly understand your question then. The example I posted was meant to fix the animation queue build-up issue that was happening. Can you be more specific about the behavior you're trying to address? Thanks!

Comment: When "Slide Down" is clicked, the panel will slide down and last for 2 seconds before it automatically slides up. 

Now do this: 
1. repeatly click "Slide Down" to show the panel and then click "Slide Up" immediately to hide the panel; 
2. after doing above for several times, click "Slide Down" immediately (don't click "Slide Up" this time), you will see that the panel slides down and slides up really quickly, while the panel is supposed to slide up after 2 seconds delay.

Comment: Sorry if there is any misunderstanding, but I am trying to make this clear.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I’m able to reproduce the bug but I’m afraid I'm not familiar enough with Angular to figure out what’s going on. Sorry!